# Regex that catches all relative and absolute links from a html string

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to catch catch all links from multiple websites. For that I have gathered the entire html file. I need a regular expression that puts all of them in an array.

I dont want to collect any image files or other code files. Just the html from the pages themselves.

---

I want It to collect all links like this:

```
/https://www.hello.com
/https://www.hello.com/index.php
/https://www.hello.com/world
/https://www.hello.com/world.php
/https://www.hello.com/world.html
/https://hello.com
/https://hello.com/world
/http://www.hello.com
/http://www.hello.com/world
/http://hello.com
/http://hello.com/world
/www.hello.com
/www.hello.com/world
/hello.com
/hello.com/world
/hello
/hello/world
```

But not like this:

```
hello 
hello/world
hello.png
hello.zip
/hello/world.png
/hello/world.js
```

---

What regular expression would I need for this? Or is there a better way? (maybe by collecting a's)

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a legit question

Comment: "is there a better way?": Well, a regex can't do this totally robust (by the nature of the HTML language). But the alternative would be to use an HTML/XML parser, which might be totally overkill for your simple task. So I'd go for regex.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you define "link" as hyperlinks in the form of `<a href="...">`. The following regex (already in the form of a PHP string) should be a good start*:

```
'<\\s*a\\s*[^>]*href\\s*=\\s*"([^"]+)"'
```

[Test this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kQyLQT/1)

When using this with `preg_match($regex, $html, $match)`, the `$match[1]` gives you the link, however, it is in an encoded form (it might contain html entities). To remove those, use `html_entity_decode`.

```
$link = html_entity_decode($match[1]);
```

You should also exclude links which are just fragments of the same site, that are links starting with the hash symbol: `$link[0] == '#'`

---

*This regex is not conform to the definition of the HTML language (I think this is impossible to do 100% correctly). The regex for example fails for links where the attribute is not wrapped in double quotes (they might be unquoted or quoted in single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Something like [PHPQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery) may be preferable to using a regex in this case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for an explanation of why.